# How could I print out a debug message in PowerShell cmdlet but not WriteObject as return value?

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to build a PowerShell cmdlet with C#. In a function, I want to print one line log and return an object. If in both place I use `WriteObject()`, I could see them in the PowerShell window. But if I use a variable to get the output my cmdlet, it gets both the string and object. How could I let the variable only get the object I'm about to return?

e.g.

```
public override void ExecuteCmdlet()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> returnValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    WriteObject("Debug Log"); // Print log

    // ... do something ...

    WriteObject(returnValue); // Return value
}
```

Assume my cmdlet named `foo`. In PowerShell window, if I run

```
$ret = foo
$ret.Count
```

The output is 2.

```
$ret
```

The output contains both the debug message and the dictionary. Any idea to let `$ret` contains the dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WriteDebug()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writedebug(v=vs.85).aspx) to write to the `Debug` stream:

```
public override void ExecuteCmdlet()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> returnValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    WriteDebug("Debug Log"); // Print log

    // ... do something ...

    WriteObject(returnValue); // Return value
}
```

---

```
PS C:\> @(foo).Count
1
PS C:\> $DebugPreference = 'Continue' # show debug output, but don't halt exection
PS C:\> @(foo).Count
Debug Log
1
PS C:\> $ret = foo
Debug Log
PS C:\> $ret.Count
1
```

---

*Note: you could also write to the `Verbose` stream (`WriteVerbose()`), if the purpose is to passively provide diagnostic output without necessarily interrupting execution*

Comment: WriteDebug and WriteVerbose needs additional parameter when using cmdlet. Is there anyway to get the output without the -Verbose or -Debug?

Comment: Not without polluting the output. Do you get any errors? Cmdlet.WriteDebug and Cmdlet.WriteVerbose shouldn't require anything more that the message text?

Comment: No errors, just no output if I don't turn on the debug output or without -Debug. I'd like to let me user do not need any further steps and no more parameters and then get the message which is not included in the output object.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to use `WriteVerbose()`, which will not need to ask for additional commands/statements, just `-vb` in the parameter list. Thanks!

Comment: Actually... you can set VerbosePreference. The effect of the user providing -Verbose is to set VerbosePreference inside the cmdlet. You can set it directly.